# Regular expression doesn't work as expected

Tags: regex

How can it be that this regular expression also returns strings that have a _ underscore as their last character?

It should only return strings with alphabetical characters, mixed lower- and uppercase.

`However, the regular expression returns: 'action_'`

```
 $regEx = '/^([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]*[\S]$|^([a-zA-Z])*[\S]$|^[a-zA-Z]*[\S]$/';
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your expression?

Comment: Why does \S appear inside of square brackets? Doesn't that define a character class containing two chars, "\" and "S"?

Comment: This is an odd RE: You've got 3 alternatives and the 2nd and 3rd alternatives are exactly the same so the 3rd alternative will never match because if it could, the 2nd alternative will already have matched.

Also, the 2nd alternative will only match when the ([a-zA-Z])* part matches nothing otherwise the 1st alternative will match it.

Comment: @Benson: [\S] is redundant, it could be just \S -- It's useful if you want to add more classes, for example: [\w\s].  "\" must be escaped to be taken literally: [\\\]

Comment: Simplified down, the expression is '/^[a-zA-Z]*[\S]$/' which removes the grouping of the first character of the expression. Seems unnecessary to your question though.

Comment: You say the regex **returns** action_ - What language are you using? Perl?  Your regex only returns true or false and your capture groups aren't set correctly to capture the whole word.

Comment: @Adrian: it looks like PHP, so the OP is probably talking about the result of a preg_match call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[\S]` will match everything that is not whitespace, including underscore.

Also, your expression is very odd!

If you want a string that only contains letters, then use `^[a-zA-Z]*$` or `^[a-zA-Z]+$` (depending on if blank is allowed or not).

If you're trying to do something else, you will need to expand on what that is.

Comment: /s lowercase means whitespace

Comment: Almost. \s lowercase means whitespace - note the slash direction.

Comment: Whoops sorry! Funny mobile keyboard layout!

Answer (score 5):

Because \S means "not whitespace character", \S matches _

A group should not have an underscore though, so, if you meant that, it could be that you are getting the whole match back and not just the first group.

Please show how are you using the regex to clarify that, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

\S matches any non-whitespace char - thus _

Answer (score 0):

You should show the text and what part from you want to extract from it.
Regular expression shouldn't be so big like yours.

Work on small expression batches... At this size, is very difficult to help you.